# Why on iOS10 on swipe on a push notification function does not run?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Why on iOS10 on swipe on a push notification `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function does not run?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
```

I've putted breakpoints on this function, later when I receive my push notification while my screen was locked, I swipe it to open the push notification and in this moment this function should be fired. But it does not.

What is wrong? Or maybe something was changed for iOS10?

Answer (score 0):

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate is called when notification is received while the app is running in foreground. When user swipes on the notification from home screen the appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called with notification as the data object.

Comment: then where should I put my code for implementing code when user swipes to open notification?

Comment: You should check the launching options in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ` method

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions) { //launchOptions is not nil
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        if (apsInfo) { 
            // launch the desired viewController
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

I think that every interection with push norificaion is handled in didrecevieremotenotification method, you have state in aplication to know was message received while in app or did user click on notification, i think you can not interect with notification if user swipe to dissmis that notification, if he seipe to open notification it will call didreceivepushnotification method.